# Call function in views.py from command line (django)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a function defined in the views file of my django app, from the command line. Is there a way to do this?

I understand view functions are supposed to be called from a request but I need this function to be called from a cron eventually.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Thanks, this worked although the django site doesn't have any examples, so I used this site: http://thingsilearned.com/2009/03/13/adding-custom-commands-to-managepy-and-django-adminpy/